# How did color spaces get their names?

Tags: color, color-management, color-spaces, rgb, cmyk

Why RGB instead of BGR, GBR or perhaps GRB?

Why CMYK instead of YMCK, KMCY, CKMY, YKMC and etc?

Comment: "Why CMYK instead of YMCK, KMCY, CKMY, YKMC and etc?" Why not CMYK?  "Why RGB instead of BGR, GBR or perhaps GRB?" Why not RGB?

Comment: If i answer correctly can i pass over the bridge ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Is this from the original LEGO movie which I have watched when I was a child?

Comment: @ Oscar,  Your quest is to seek the Holy Grail. Ask Monty Python.

Comment: @AlaskaMan "I will"

Comment: It's pure convention. I've seen different ones used by knowledgeable folks in different context.

Comment: This question should remain open... I am curious now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume RGB is in that order simply because it is the common spectral order — RoyGBiv, in other words. You will sometimes see BRG or otherwise when a particular computer image format happens to store the channel data in that order.

CMYK, on the other hand, is that way because that's the order the inks are normally applied in process color. See for example [this article on four-color printing](https://the-print-guide.blogspot.com/2009/07/ink-sequence-4c-process-beyond.html).

Comment: Now the question becomes "Why CMYK is applied in CMYK order"

Comment: That I don't know. It might simply be that that order is the order of the complements of RGB, and that became convention. But there may be something about the color mixing properties.

Comment: The "laydown sequence" or sequence is not a rule. The press operator can choose any order for any number of reasons. K in the sequence taken for blacK takes its name from "Key" which to a pressman means first down. The first down hue is chosen such that subsequent inks can be registered with the first. Cyan is also used as a key as it is easy to see. Yellow would be the worst. The lighting in the pressroom is often bluer than you might want so that yellow on press can be more easily seen.

Comment: Spectral order still depends on whether one reads from right to left or left to right, or starts with lower frequencies or lower wavelengths.

Comment: @MichaelC Yes, but that particular order is widely seen as the "normal" one at least in the US and Western Europe.

Comment: @mattdm Not always. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ktN.jpg) quite typical chart. Or [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvEiG.png). They're both in BGR order, rather than RGB.

Comment: In science, maybe. In popular culture, I'm pretty confident that "red orange yellow..." is rainbow order.

Comment: I submit that if you saw crayons in a package and they had violet on the left going to red on the right, you'd think it unusual.

Comment: I used work an offset litho press. We almost always printed KCMY.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it’s as simple as the positions occupied by the colors on the spectrum.
[image]

Comment: Na, that would be too easy

Comment: Generally filters pass their name and block their complement. 
A red filter passes red and blocks cyan.
A green filter passes green and blocks magenta.
A blue filter passes blue and blocks yellow.
A cyan filter passes cyan and blocks red.
A magenta filter passes magenta and blocks green.
A yellow filter passes yellow and blocks blue.

Red Cadillacs BY General Motors was commonly used.
Red – Cyan   Blue – Yellow   Green – Magenta.
In printing, black results when C+Y+M overlap. This black is too weak. Black ink is added to boost the contrasts. The black is called a Kicker thus CMYK.